# Update stored db data from form when which field is altered is unknown. Using PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page with several different input fields and checkboxes that, when filled out, are stored in a mysql database using PDO. On another page, there is an option to update the info that the user has stored.

How do I write the code to update when I have no idea what fields the user has changed? It seems a overkill to write ALTER TABLE `shops` CHANGE field1, field2, field3, ....." when the user has only changed one field. I need to know what has been changed and then update and store it..

I'm quite sure there is a very simple answer but my PHP skills are rustier than the Titanic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, you get those fields - field1, field2 by requesting the form what changes the user made http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also, it's very unlikely you want an `ALTER TABLE` command. It sounds like you want to update *data*, not structure, so you would want `UPDATE TABLE...`

Comment: You are using the wrong DDL instruction. ALTER changes the structure/characteristics of the specified table - not the data within the table. You should be looking at INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE and REPLACE INTO to actually affect the data. When you submit a form it will have the input name and it's value.

Comment: Ed and Jeff, thanks a lot. That cleared some of the fog for me. I have done this before, but that was in the 90's...